# Operatorial CTP / in-in formalism for sourced GW production?

Tags: cosmology, gravitational-waves, cosmological-inflation, qft-in-curved-spacetime, semiclassical

**Introduction / context** -
The inflationary paradigm of modern cosmology is a very powerful and predictive framework in which we can trace the primordial cosmological perturbations as originated by zero-point quantum fluctuations.
The observed primordial cosmological perturbations are just zero-point quantum fluctuations - they saturate the uncertainty relation - parametrically amplified by the rapid expansion. This process is strictly quantum mechanical. Today, however, *the cosmological perturbations appear as classical large macroscopic fluctuations* - i.e. they have large occupation numbers and the classicality corresponds to an uncertainty much bigger than the minimal one allowed by the rules of quantum mechanics.
I recall that we have two relics from inflation: the scalar primordial spectrum $\zeta$ (comoving curvature perturbation) and the irreducible primordial spectrum of gravitational waves $h_{ij}$. [ https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0210162 ] The scalar perturbation $\zeta$ acts as a second-order classical source of gravitational waves, upon horizon re-entry in radiation/matter dominated eras. [ https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0612013 ]

**The problem** - Present studies calculate the leading-order contribution to the induced GW spectrum from these $2^{\rm nd}$-order source [again, https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0612013 ], in a semi-classical expanding FLRW background. It starts by solving the classical equation of motion for the GW in the presence of the source $\mathcal{S}_{ij}$ by using Green's function.
\begin{align}
h_{ij}'' + 2\mathcal{H}\,h_{ij}' - \nabla^2\,h_{ij} = 16\pi G\,S_{ij}
\end{align}
where $h_{ij}$ is the GW field and $\mathcal{H}$ is the Hubble rate in conformal coordinates.
The final goal is to calculate the power spectrum $\sim \left\langle h_{\bf k_1}(\tau) \, h_{\bf k_2}(\tau) \right\rangle $ that is, the two-point cosmological correlator.

**The question** - I am aware, from field theory I, that QFT encodes also the classical dynamics. In fact it is straightforward to appreciate the relation between classical/quantum dynamics in the functional formulation where I am literally able to expand a theory as a formal power series in $\hbar \rightarrow 0$. However, such connection does not appear - to me - trivial when the theory is formulated in terms of operators and states.

1. What is the connection between classical/quantum theory in the operatorial formulation of in-in formalism (or equivalently of operatorial in/out)? How is rephrased the expasion in $\hbar$ - of the functional formulation of QFT - in terms of operators? (Guess: pointer operators?)
2. Can I use the CTP/in-in operatorial formalism - which treats $h_{ij}$ as a non-commuting quantum field - to calculate the gravitational waves produced by the classical $\zeta$-sourcing during post-inflationary eras? (analogously to what described in "problem") Again, you sould consider that the final goal is to calculate the two-point cosmological correlator $\left\langle \hat{h}_{\bf k_1}(\tau)\,\hat{h}_{\bf k_2}(\tau) \right\rangle$.

**About in-in formalism** Weinberg's paper https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0506236

For the sake of brevity, some point may appar to be formulated with carelessness. Please apologize me. Thanks in advance. Regards